# Angular translate on head description or keywords

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Someone succeed to put angular translation on head meta ?

I've tried that but without success

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ 'head.keywords' | translate }}"/>
<meta name="description" content="{{ 'head.title' | translate }}"/>
<title translate="head.title">Title</title>
```

Just the title works...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the solution :

```
<meta name="keywords" translate translate-attr-content="head.keywords" />
<meta name="description" translate translate-attr-content="head.description"/>
```

Comment: And don't forget to move `ng-app="myApp"` from the body to the HTML tag like I did :-)

Comment: I had the same problem. With this solution, what does Facebook and other social networks show ? Because they keep showing the code between brackets for my website...